# Redirect visitor based on cookie

Tags: php, cookies, redirect

im starting to learn php, a little application im building needs to send visitors to specific pages based on if they have a preferance cookie and if so go to specific page based on which cookie.

so at one part of my application a visitor will be faced with three links, when a visitor clicks a link a cookie remebering the visitors preference will be sent so

```
Link1 = Prefcookie1
Link2 = Prefcookie2
Link3 = Prefcookie3
```

at another page it needs to

Check for any prefcookies
if no redirect to index1

If yes check which precookie

```
If prefcookie = prefcookie1 redirect to index
if prefcookie = prefcookie2 redirect to index1
if precookie = prefcookie3 redirect to index3
```

Or could somthing similar be achieved through htaccess?

any help greatly appreciated, its that last thing to complete this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP would work fine for this:

```
<?
if($_COOKIE['prefcookie'] == "prefcookie1")
 {header("Location: index");}
elseif($_COOKIE['prefcookie'] == "prefcookie2")
 {header("Location: index2");}
elseif($_COOKIE['prefcookie'] == "prefcookie3")
 {header("Location: index3");}
else
 {header("Location: index1");}
?>
```

or so

Comment: Thanks for that, ive been using this code while developing parts of this application, when i go directly to the check cookie file it works as planned and reditects a user based on their preferance when it came time to finish it all off and put this code into the index file it would not redirect people as it should and loads a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

You can read a cookie in PHP see http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

But you mention htaccess which suggests you plan on doing this with RewriteRules in Apache, which has nothing to do with PHP. The answer to if you can do this with RewriteRules is yes although you will need a server that supports it. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html (Section on server variables)

Comment: I only mentioned htaccess as it came up as a suggested answer when inputting the question, i prefer to try do this with php to avoid compatibility issues

Answer (score 0):

You can insert "check script" to all page you want redirect. insert in first line.

ex: by "thefinn93"

```
<?
if($_COOKIE['prefcookie'] == "prefcookie1")
 {header("Location: index");}
elseif($_COOKIE['prefcookie'] == "prefcookie2")
 {header("Location: index2");}
elseif($_COOKIE['prefcookie'] == "prefcookie3")
 {header("Location: index3");}
else
 {header("Location: index1");}
?>
```

sd

Comment: Thanks for that, ive been using this code while developing parts of this application, when i go directly to the check cookie file it works as planned and reditects a user based on their preferance when it came time to finish it all off and put this code into the index file it would not redirect people as it should and loads a blank screen